# como puedo enviar la factura de la orden de compra por correo electronico

Tags: python, djangorestframework

quiero que cuando una compra tenga un estado 'aprobado' en el modelo order se envie un pdf al correo del cliente. alguien me puede sugerir algo con respecto a eso?

estos son los modelos de la orden

```
class Order(models.Model):
usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
estado = models.CharField(max_length=50)
precio_total = models.IntegerField()
invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=increment_invoice_number, null=True, blank=True)
fecha = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Fecha", default=now)

class Meta:
    verbose_name="Order"
    verbose_name_plural = "Orders"
    ordering = ['-id']

def __str__(self):
    return 'Order {}'.format(self.invoice_no)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
producto = models.ForeignKey(Caracteristica, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
orden = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
cantidad = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.id)

def get_cost(self):
    return self.price * self.cantidad
```

gracias por su colaboracion.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo de esta forma:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

Pero en *settings.py* tienes que escribir el siguiente código:

```
#SMPT CONFIGURATION

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smpt.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' #si usas gmail
EMAIL PORT = 587 # puerto de gmail
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = example@gmail.com #tu correo
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = password #contrasena del correo
```

Además, en *gmail* tienes que ir a este link: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
y pones en permitir el acceso de aplicaciones poco seguras.